# Pipes in Bash: One at a Time (Line by Line) or All at Once

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

First, I create 5 files

```
$ touch a b c d e
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e
```

In the following example, `xargs` seems to get all the results from `find` via the pipe *all at once:*

```
$ find . -type f | xargs -t echo | wc -w
echo ./c ./b ./a ./d ./e
5
```

In the following example, `xargs` seems to get all the results from `find` via the pipe *one at a time* (line by line):

```
$ find . -type f | xargs -t -i mv {} {}.bak | wc  -w
mv ./c ./c.bak
mv ./b ./b.bak
mv ./a ./a.bak
mv ./d ./d.bak
mv ./e ./e.bak
0
```

In the following example, `xargs` seems to get all the results from 'find' via the pipe *one at a time* (line by line); and `wc` seems to get all the results from `xargs` via the pipe *all at once.*

Otherwise, if `wc` got the results line by line, you would see `1` appear 5 times instead of a `5` at the end.

```
$ find . -type f | xargs -t -i echo {} | wc -w
echo ./e.bak
echo ./b.bak
echo ./c.bak
echo ./a.bak
echo ./d.bak
5
```

So do pipes get results from previous command One at a Time (Line by Line) or All at Once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are observing comes from the `xargs` options you are using. The `-i` option specifically instructs `xargs` to create one new process for each input token, and replace the `{}` placeholder with that token.

Pipes by themselves do not stipulate any specific behavior; many kernels will pass one full I/O buffer at a time (hence the many questions about I/O buffering with pipes, along the lines of "this command doesn't seem to do anything in a pipe" when the actual symptom is just that the output buffer isn't full yet).

Comment: `find . -type f | xargs -t -i echo {} |  xargs -t echo` This command demonstrates what you wrote is right. `-i` changes the behavior of `xargs`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (By the by, the default action of `xargs` is `echo` so you don't actually need to spell it out.) The first `xargs` prints one at a time as you requested and the second collects them all back on one line, which is the primary use case for `xargs`.

Comment: Does it also mean `xargs -t echo` actually replace all the newline after each result with a space? while  `cat` preserves the newline as in `find . -type f | xargs -t -i echo {} | cat`

Comment: Again, the *primary purpose* of `xargs` is to collect as many arguments as possible on the command line of the command it is spawning. The spaces are supplied by `echo` when it receives these five arguments in its `argv` array.

Answer (score 1):

`|` simply passes `stdout` from a process to the `stdin` of the next process. For example, `find . -type f | grep "bla"` translates to (roughly): Run `find . -type f`, and whatever this process prints to stdout, pass it as it is to `grep "bla"` as stdin.

It is up to the receiving process to determine what to do with it. `xargs` applies the given substitution on each line. `wc`, on the other hand, keeps track of various statistics (words, lines etc.) until there is no more input, and then prints it out.

It might be useful to read up on stdout, stdin etc. -  http://www.learnlinux.org.za/courses/build/shell-scripting/ch01s04.html

Comment: This sounds a plausible explanation. It is up to **the `command` after the pipe** to decide how to use the data passed on from the previous command(process). So it seems the data are sometimes processed line by line or sometimes all at once( as the `wc` example shows).